# Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot issues

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I know this question was asked earlier. But I tried all option, nothing worked for me so far. My laptop Lenovo Thinkpad. In the Bios UEFI/Legacy boot, I have Legacy only. I had Mint19 and Windows 10 dual boot system. That was working fine. For some reason, I decided to replace mint19 with ubuntu 18. After the installation, Grub boot menu shows both windows10 and ubuntu. But I can only boot Ubuntu. My win 10 doesn't boot anymore.

I read this [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

There someone suggested executing a script that generated some system information. I have the result.txt after executing the script. The RESULTS.txt in my Google Drive:- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JAOcZaEGZZbV4q96ADw9cqDnaK_bNLwI/view

Could you please suggest how to fix this issue?

**Extra information:-**

Here is the situation. I think my windows installation and files are in /dev/sda1 ntfs and /dev/sda2 extended. I think I have to merge /dev/sda2 extended into /dev/sda1 ntfs. I have no idea how to do it? I must not delete the partition to avoid windows files. Could you please suggest how can put both /dev/sda1 ntfs and /dev/sda2 extended without losing data?

[image]

Comment: Install instructions say to shrink Windows with Windows tools & backup Windows. I hope you at least did the backup as you only have the Windows boot partition, not main c: drive partition. Automatic install would not have overwritten Windows. And manualy install should have shown the Windows NTFS partitions, unless you left Windows hibernated or fast start up on. Fast start up prevents Linux NTFS driver from fully seeing NTFS partitions.

Comment: Well, I had mint and windows. When I installed ubuntu, I formatted only mint partition. Selected that space for ubuntu. I kept windows partition as it was before. I didn't keep any backup. It's ok if I lose some stuff from the existing windows. Is there any way to boot windows now? Or do I need to reinstall it again?

Comment: You have no Windows to boot, only a tiny boot partition. You will need to shrink & move Linux partition & then extended partition to make room for a primary NTFS partition as that will be what Windows wants. It may work with a logical only because your boot partition is a primary. Windows does not require a separate boot partition so you possibly could also just expand it. Windows is also known with MBR, not to include the Linux logical partitions when it does major updates or installs. So backup partition tabel & data before Windows install or plan on new Ubuntu install.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I added extra questions about how to get recover windows data.  I don't know how to do it. Please guide me with more information

Comment: The extended is not a real partition, but a container for your logical partitions. It has no data of its own. If you did not have good backups, stop using system. You may be able to recover some data, but wherever new data was written is not recoverable.You could start by using Recuva -- to see what it finds. If it doesn't work, you should then try RecoverMyFiles -- to see what it finds.
NTFS file recovery suggestion by Mark Phelps (not free but works)
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12490412&postcount=4 With Linux there is testdisk/photorec, but NTFS tools may work better for NTFS.